# Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to upload a csv into MySQL using the Workbench, and so far all my attempts have proven fruitless.

I initially attempted to use the "Upload" function, but it complained about any null/empty fields I had.

I am now attempting to use this function:

```
LOAD DATA infile 'C:\\temp\\SubEq.csv'
INTO TABLE cas_asset_register.subequipment
fields terminated BY ','
lines terminated BY '\n'
(seid, parentme, @vparentse, name, status, description, equipmenttype, comments, removed, active, @vsupplierid)
SET
ParentSE = nullif(@vparentse,''),
SupplierId = nullif(@vsupplierid,'')
;
```

But again, it appears to be complaining about (possibly) the same thing:

> Error Code: 1261. Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns

I have had a look at the answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646781/mysql-error-1261-row-1-doesnt-contain-data-for-all-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219491/row-does-not-contain-data-for-all-columns) question, but neither have solved my issue.

The table create query:

```
CREATE TABLE `subequipment` (
  `SEId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ParentME` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ParentSE` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EquipmentType` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comments` text,
  `Removed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `SupplierId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SEId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique_Constraint_ME` (`Name`,`ParentME`,`Active`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique_Constraint_SE` (`Name`,`ParentSE`,`Active`),
  KEY `ParentME` (`ParentME`),
  KEY `ParentSE` (`ParentSE`),
  KEY `EquipmentType` (`EquipmentType`),
  KEY `fk_subequipment_supplierequipment` (`SupplierId`),
  KEY `fk_subequipment_status_idx` (`Status`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subequipment_majorequipment` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentME`) REFERENCES `majorequipment` (`MEId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subequipment_status` FOREIGN KEY (`Status`) REFERENCES `componentstatus` (`StatusName`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subequipment_subequipment` FOREIGN KEY (`ParentSE`) REFERENCES `subequipment` (`SEId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subequipment_supplierequipment` FOREIGN KEY (`SupplierId`) REFERENCES `supplierinfo_equipment` (`SupplierId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_subequipment_userdefinedcode` FOREIGN KEY (`EquipmentType`) REFERENCES `userdefinedcode` (`UDCId`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As you can see from my upload query, I am expecting "ParentSE" and "SupplierId" to be empty, even though they are foreign key fields.

Each line of the csv is properly indexed (i.e. there *are* enough fields to match the table):

```
1,1,,P7YCGPF,Abg va hfr,Nfcver Npre Yncgbc,13,"Qngr npdhverq: 61/52/7566
Zbqry: 0297T
Frevny Ahzore: YKE057551588125P16156",0,1,
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: are you saying query from db to csv what tools you used from query to csv

Comment: I'm sorry @reds I don't quite follow what you're asking?

Comment: @Ben Looks like the error is coming from the empty string values in your `.csv` files. The `Error 1261` is a result of MySQL not having anything to insert rather than being able to insert `NULL`. So if your `.csv` file is something like: `'a', 'b', 'c', '', 'e'` MySQL does not know what to do with the `''` value unless it is changed from `''` to `NULL` like: `'a', 'b', 'c', 'NULL', 'e'`. I am not sure I am understanding your question correctly but if this answer seems correct I am willing to help further.

Comment: @ThoseKind I feel; like you're probably on the right track, as I am expecting at least two of these values to be empty (hence the `SET
ParentSE = nullif(@vparentse,'')` sections). I'm just not sure if this is being implemented correctly

Comment: Your `NULLIF` statement looks correct so the only other thing I could think of is double checking the `.csv` files to make sure that they do indeed contains those `''` empty strings like you expect. Once you have confirmed this I cannot see why it would be going wrong. You could write a script that parses your `.csv` files to and replaces those `''` with `NULL`, but I am not sure if this is viable for you. Sorry I can't help you further on the MySQL side but I'd look into it further and see what you can find. If nothing I could help with a program to replace `''`, but that's up to you.

Comment: What do you mean by this `1,1,,` double comma in the csv file

Answer (score 5):

Does your data in any of your fields in the csv file contain commas? This screws up the field termination criteria when you're trying to upload it into MySQL. If this is the case, try saving it as a tab delimited txt file and replacing

```
fields terminated BY ','
```

with

```
fields terminated BY '\t'
```

Sorry if this is not the right answer to your question, I wanted to post this as a comment but my reputation is not high enough :P

Comment: No where in the csv are there any commas where there ought not be. As you can see from the excerpt, the error is throwing at "Row 1", which I have included for comparison. however, I will save it as a tab-delimited and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error for the last line in my CSV file. This may not solve your problem, but it solved mine and hope it helps someone.

For me I needed a carriage return character at the very end of the file to get onto a new line. Imports without errors now

Comment: I'm rather late to the thread, but this works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and comparing the columns in the CSV file and the table in my database resolved the issue. The number of columns, the column types, and in some cases empty values for string types (e.g., "" for string type) should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the file had to be tab-separated. I read some users reported that the file had to be semicolon-separated.